# Promise reject paused with an exception yet no error is log

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

Below is a Nodejs piece of code. I'm querying a Mongodb using mongoose. This piece of code gets paused at "Line A" with message "Paused on Exception". console shows no errors. Meanwhile this seem to happen only when I run in VS Code. Running the app from console raises no exception.

I'm inclined to say this a VS Code issue. Has anyone seen/faced same or something similar?

```js
Board.findOne({ boardId: id }, function (err, data) {
 if (!err) {
  data ? resolve(data.children) : reject(data);  //Line A
  // line above pauses execution with this message: "Paused on Exception"
  // No error logged in console. And this seem to happen only in VS code.
 }else{
  reject(err);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Catching the promise exception does not help either as the caught error is null. 

Note: The entire piece of code is within a promise:
`var newPromise = new Promise (function(resolve, reject){
    //db query code in question
}).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
 });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose already supports promises, so you can rewrite your code to this:

```
return Board.findOne({ boardId: id }).then(function(data) {
  if (! data) throw new Error('data empty');
  return data.children;
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Perhaps this also solves your VS Code issue.